Poor performance with MariaDB (11) and utf8mb4_unicode_ci (vs utf8mb4_general_ci)
We have a large database using MariaDB 11, and up until now, we have been working with various collations, primarily utf8mb4_general_ci. As part of a standardization process, we attempted to encode all tables with a single collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci. However, two primary SQL queries have become significantly slower, taking over 8 seconds compared to the previous 3 seconds. Upon examining the execution plan, we noticed that MariaDB can no longer utilize an index that was working before. Additionally, there's another query that performs an order by/group by operation on a large table, which never finishes executing, though I can't identify any index-related issues.
It's quite challenging for me to share or explain these queries here, as they are complex and involve multiple tables. So, my question is more general in nature.
Is this behavior normal? Is it bad to use the utf8mb4_general_ci collation for all tables?
I tried using utf8mb4_general_ci only for one large table and continued with utf8mb4_unicode_ci for the rest. The queries ran faster, but I'm now forced to explicitly specify the same collation when comparing columns.

utf8mb4_general_ci is not an encoding, but collation. Utf8 and utf8mb4 are encodings. You need to use a collation that sorts your string columns in the right order. You should preferably use a single collation in your database. Rather than asking a too generic question, it would be better if you showed the queries that run slowly after collation change, include explain befire and after collation change and the table definitions of the underlying tables.

general has fewer/incorrect rules, thus is faster. unicode has sortings for every language. If your table content doesn't even need a correct sort order for every possible character consider using a more specific collation like f.e. utf8mb4_swedish_ci. Do you really meant "_utf8mb3general_ci"?

@AmigoJack thx for answering. Yes, utf8mb3_general_ci. When we migrated from MySQL to MariaDB, mariadb-dump forced mb3 over mb4, I don't know why. We will try with a specific collation, like you said. Thx.

"can no longer utilize an index " -- That sounds like an inconsistency in collations; let's see the query and SHOW CREATE TABLE.  Also:   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
